# How do I create a text file for every other file in a directory in windows?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, file-io

complete newbie using windows here.

I have a program that requires me to have a text file for every file in a folder containing information about that file. The text files must also have the same file name as the file they are describing, so for example in a folder like this:

```
file1.abc
file2.abc
file3.abc
file4.abc
```

I would need to have the following:

```
file1.abc
file1.abc.txt
file2.abc
file2.abc.txt
file3.abc
file3.abc.txt
file4.abc
file4.abc.txt
```

up until now I have been doing this all manually which for folders containing upwards of 50 to 100 files is time consuming and less than ideal. What I am asking is, is there a way to automate the file creation using a batch script or similar? and if there is would someone be able to provide a code snippet to use?

Thanks in advance

P.S if it helps, I am using windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

creator.bat:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.abc) do echo %%f > %%f.txt
```

If your filenames contain spaces it gets slightly more complicated:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.abc) do echo %%f > "%%~f.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.*) do if /i "%%~xf" neq ".txt" echo whatever > %%f.txt
```

This will place the text `whatever` in each new .txt file created.

files already with extension `.txt` are excepted.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%a in (*) do if not exist "%%a.txt" (
        set "create=1"
        if "%%~xa"==".txt" for %%b in ("%%~na") do if not "%%~xb"=="" set "create="
        if defined create type nul > "%%a.txt"
    )
```

This should create all the required files only when they do not exist, not overwritting previous generated ones and avoiding the generation of unnedded files.